# Cannot resolve method execute ( saving image file in Google Drive )

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to take a picture and save it to Google Drive. I do not know what to do with the " Cannot resolve method "execute" " error. 
My `saveFileToDrive` code looks like this:

```
private void saveFileToDrive() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                /*// File's metadata.
                File body = new File();
                body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

                // File's binary content
                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);
*/

                // File's content.
                java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("TESR");
                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

                // File's metadata.
                File body = new File();
                body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

                File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setOcr(true).execute();

                fileid = file.getId();

                if (file != null) {
                    showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle() + " with the following id: " + fileid);
                    startCameraIntent();
                }
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

and I keep getting the error at this line:

```
File file =service.files().insert(body,mediaContent).setOcr(true).execute();
```

The error says: "cannot resolve method 'execute()'
I also tried it without the OCR part, and it didn`t work

Please help me with this error, because now this is the only error that I can't handle and without this I can't compile my app.

Answer (score 0):

Since this issue is prior to the app being compiled, it may have something to do with the app's dependencies. Try to add the drive services in your `build.gradle` as indicate in the guides

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev235-1.22.0'
}
```